# How to create a function that returns an index of the first repeated value in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

My task is:

1. To create a function called, `indexOfRepeatedValue(arr)`,
2. To create a `firstIndex` variable inside that function,
3. To check (using a `for` loop) which number (in a given array) repeats itself as first,
4. And to assign the index of that number to the previously created `firstIndex` variable

The given array of values is this,

```
const givenArr = [2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4];
```

So, for this given array the first number to be repeated is 2. Then the value of `firstIndex` variable should be equal to 0 (after returning the value of `firstIndex` variable from inside that function).

My code so far looks like this,

```
const givenArr = [2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4];

function indexOfRepeatedValue(arr) {
    let firstIndex;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === ) { //The place where I clearly miss something
            firstIndex = ;
        }
        break;
    }
    return firstIndex;
}

console.log(indexOfRepeatedValue(givenArr));
```

I have no idea what to put inside that `if` statement. Using of `indexOf` function, or something like that, is prohibited (hadn't learned that yet). Thanks in advance! I'm hungry to learn.

Comment: You somehow need to store the values inside the loop. Otherwise you don't stand a chance to know if any value appeared before in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Set` and if the loop encounters an element that is already present in the set that is where you have found a match and you can set the `firstIndex` variable.

NOTE: `firstIndex` is `undefined` if the array has no duplicates.

```js
const givenArr = [2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4];

function indexOfRepeatedValue(arr) {
    let firstIndex;
    let s = new Set();
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (s.has(arr[i])) { 
            firstIndex = arr.indexOf(arr[i]);
            break;
        }else {
          s.add(arr[i])
        }
    }
    return firstIndex;
}

console.log(indexOfRepeatedValue(givenArr));
```

Based on OP's comment

If you don't want to have an additional data structure you can check whether the
element that you are currently at is already present. But try using the first approach, if possible.

```js
const givenArr = [2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4];

function indexOfRepeatedValue(arr) {
    let firstIndex;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr.indexOf(arr[i]) < i) { 
            firstIndex = arr.indexOf(arr[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
    return firstIndex;
}

console.log(indexOfRepeatedValue(givenArr));
```

Comment: Is it possible to solve that without the `set` function? :)

Comment: Ya it is! You can use any data structure that can tell whether that item has already been encountered in the loop. But `Set` is the best for doing this.

Comment: I've added another solution without the `Set`, take a look. @szachy113

Comment: That's much closer, friend. But it uses that `indexOf` function. I wonder if you can solve it without that (as I specified in the topic).

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You need to know if the element you're currently at has already been traversed.

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object to store the first found index and check  if the object contains the value of the array. If found return the index.

```js
function indexOfRepeatedValue(array) {
    const indices = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        const value = array[i];
        if (value in indices) return indices[value];
        indices[value] = i;
    }
    return -1; // or any other value if not found
}

console.log(indexOfRepeatedValue([7, 13, 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4]));
```

Comment: Is it possible to solve that without the using of an object type? :)

Comment: funny, you accepted an answer with `indexOf` and a much more complex data type `Set`.

Comment: You got to read the comments carefully, Nina :) But still, I'm new to stack overflow, still learning how to manage questions.

Comment: I guess your answer makes sense too, but the code is not that crystal clear for me personally.

Comment: there is nothing hidden. the object is the most important type of javascript. all other types have their origin in it.

Comment: No question about that, but it doesn't change my personal preferences. Anyway, thanks for your answer!

Comment: you can only lead a horse to water seems

Answer (score 0):

## terse

```js
const findRepeatedIndex = a => [...a].findIndex(function(x) {
  return (l = this.l = this.l || {}) && l[x] && 1 || (l[x] = 1) && 0;
});
console.log(findRepeatedIndex([2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4]));
```

- spread syntax is used to skip array mutation
- `findIndex` finds **the first** truthy evaluated index or -1 if not found
- a `function` enables `this` context where arrow syntax would not
- `this` enables adding `l` to the array to keep track
- the `return` is truthy if `l[x]` is `1`
- else `(l[x] = 1) && 0` combines assignment with falsy

Comment: why `this` ...?